# SharePoint 2013 Easy Tabs - Link to Specific Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

**Goal: Hyperlink goes to/makes active specified easytab tabbed web part on page**

I've been going round & round, experimenting w/differing easy tabs scripts & scripts to make linking to a specific tab possible, but w/o success. Can someone help?

**Current easy tabs** (works well itself. Loaded js file to document library, linked it to page w/content editor):
http://usermanagedsolutions.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx

**Nav script on page** (tried a few, here's 2):

**1)**  script

var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
}

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})

**2)** text/javascript

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        var prefix = "tab_";
        if (hash) {
            var tab = jQuery(hash.replace(prefix,"")).attr('href');
            jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href='+tab+']').tab('show');
        }
    });
```

**Link format used to try to link to/activate specified tab**

--used F12 to find web part title ID. This example was the 2nd tab's ID

end part of link tried:

Pages/leaselinks.aspx#tab-etWPQ4

Pages/leaselinks.aspx#tab_etWPQ4

Pages/leaselinks.aspx#etWPQ4

Pages/leaselinks.aspx/#tab_etWPQ4

Can you tell what is missing or wrong?

Comment: FWIW.  I used to use that solution, but started going with JQueryui.com.  (https://jqueryui.com/tabs/).  They have customizable solutions that you can cut and paste into SharePoint.  I download the CSS and JS files locally and tweak the html to meet my needs.  I use the tabs and accordion.  Easy to use.

Comment: TY David. Excuse my ignorance, but I came across that pg b4, but don't understand how that translates to tabbing webparts? Handy for potential typed-in/text tabs but how to make them function the same?

Comment: Sorry.  I missed that one line.  Shame.  ;)

Comment: So Mark Rackleys solution is not what you are looking for?   http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

Updated... How it should work...

After selecting a tab it changed the hyperlink like so:

Original: https://mysite/leaselinks.aspx

Tab: https://mysite/leaselinks.aspx#tab_etWPQ4

Then I can use the hyperlink ending in #tab_ to direct users to the page and activate that specific tab.

This will work on occasion, guessing due to cookies, but not as an actual solution.

The EasyTabs script I am using is Chris Humbert's, plus script to adjust tab color at top I think I got from another source

(add brackets style type="text/css" at top and close script at bottom)

```
 
.et-tab{font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;padding:3px 10px;background:url("/_layouts/images/selbg.png") repeat-x;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;}
.et-activetab{background-color:#cccccc;border:solid 1px #cccccc;color:#003865;}
.et-inactivetab{background-color:#003865;border:solid 1px #003865;color:#ffffff;}
.et-separator{height:5px;background-color:#cccccc;}
.et-tabrow{white-space:nowrap;}
.et-offscreen{position:absolute;max-height:1px;max-width:1px;top:-9999px;}
```

/* Easy Tabs v 5.0 * Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Christophe Humbert * http://www.pathtosharepoint.com */
/* Easy Tabs v 5.0 * Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Christophe Humbert * http://www.pathtosharepoint.com */
(function(){
    var AP="",sec=0,Header="none",Split="No",Expand="",Print="";
    if (document.forms[0].elements["_wikiPageMode.value"]=="true"||document.forms[0].elements["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"].value=="1"){
        return;
    }
    var el=document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),p=el[el.length-1],sT,a,sep,tabRow;
    do {
        p=p.parentNode;
        sT=p.innerHTML.split("MSOZoneCell_WebPart");
        //alert(sT.length); 
    }
    while (sT.length<4 && p.parentNode.id!="MSO_ContentTable")
    if (p.getAttribute("contenteditable")=="true"){
        return;
    }
    if (p.nodeName=="DIV"){
        //alert("in if");
        //alert(p.innerHTML);
        sep=document.createElement("div");
        p.insertBefore(sep,p.firstChild);
        tabRow=document.createElement("div");
        p.insertBefore(tabRow,p.firstChild);
        //alert(p.innerHTML);
    }
    else{
        //alert("in else")
        sep=document.createElement("td");
        var sepTR=document.createElement("tr");
        sepTR.appendChild(sep);
        tabRow=document.createElement("td");
        var tabTR=document.createElement("tr");
        tabTR.appendChild(tabRow);
        if (p.nodeName=="TBODY"){
            p.insertBefore(sepTR,p.firstChild);
            p.insertBefore(tabTR,p.firstChild);
        }
        else if (p.nodeName=="TR"){
            p.parentNode.insertBefore(tabTR,p);
            p.parentNode.insertBefore(sepTR,p);
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

`}
sep.className="et-separator";
tabRow.className="et-tabrow";
var children=p.childNodes;
p=p.parentNode;
var etRoot=[],etHeader=[],etTab=[],tabsID=[];
for (var j=0;
j<children.length;
j++){
    try{
        var d=children[j].getElementsByTagName("span");
        for (i=0;
        i<d.length;
        i++) {
            //alert (d.html);
            if(d[i].id.indexOf("WebPartTitle")==0){
                var WPid=d[i].id.replace(/WebPartTitle/,"");
                if (d[i].innerHTML.indexOf("(Hidden)")==-1) {
                    var up=d[i];
                    while (up!=children[j]){
                        if (up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id=WebPart'+WPid+' ')>=0||up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id="WebPart'+WPid+'" ')>=0){
                            WPid="et"+WPid;
                            etHeader[WPid]=up;
                            etRoot[WPid]=children[j];
                            etTab[WPid]=d[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].cloneNode(true);
                            etTab[WPid].id=WPid;
                            etTab[WPid].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
                            etTab[WPid].onclick=function(){
                                activateTab(this);
                            };
                            tabRow.appendChild(etTab[WPid]);
                            tabsID.push(WPid);
                            break;
                        }
                        up=up.parentNode;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
    catch(e){}
}
var Tabs=tabRow.getElementsByTagName("span"),TabCount=Tabs.length;
if (Split=="Yes") {
    var sd=document.createElement("div"),index=Math.floor(TabCount*0.5);
    tabRow.insertBefore(sd,Tabs[index]);
}
if(AP.length && sec>0) {
    sec=sec*1000;
    interval="";
    a=document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML="|>";
    a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick=function(){
        if(interval==""){
            this.innerHTML="||";
            interval=window.setInterval(function(){
                Autoplay();
            }
            ,sec)
        }
        else{
            this.innerHTML="|>";
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            interval=""
        }

    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
    var Autoplay=function(){
        for(i=0;
        i<TabCount;
        i++)if(Tabs[i].className=="et-tab et-activetab"){
            var j=(i+1)%TabCount;
            activateTab(Tabs[j]);
            break
        }

    };
    if (AP=="Play"){
        a.innerHTML="||";
        interval=window.setInterval(function(){
            Autoplay();
        }
        ,sec)
    };
}
if (Expand.length) {
    a=document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML=Expand;
    a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick=function(){
        for(i=0;
        i<tabsID.length;
        i++){
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className=etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/et-offscreen/g,"");
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].style.pageBreakAfter="always";
            etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display="";
        }

    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}
if (Print.length) {
    a=document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML=Print;
    a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick=function(){
        this.style.display="none";
        var f=document.getElementById("s4-workspace")||document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],ed=p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement(p.nodeName),p);
        f.appendChild(p);
        for (j=0;
        j<f.childNodes.length-1;
        j++) {
            try{
                f.childNodes[j].className+=" et-offscreen";
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
        a=document.createElement("span");
        a.innerHTML="Back to Page";
        a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
        a.onclick=function(){
            this.previousSibling.style.display="inline-block";
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            ed.parentNode.insertBefore(p,ed);
            ed.parentNode.removeChild(ed);
            for (j=0;
            j<f.childNodes.length;
            j++) {
                try{
                    f.childNodes[j].className=f.childNodes[j].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g,"");
                }
                catch(e){}
            }

        };
        tabRow.appendChild(a);
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}
function activateTab(t){
    document.cookie=tabsID.join("_")+"="+t.id+";path=/";
    for(i=0;
    i<tabsID.length;
    i++){
        etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display=Header;
        if(t.id==tabsID[i]){
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-activetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className=etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g,"");
        }
        else{
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className+=" et-offscreen";
        }

    }

}
var m=GetCookie(tabsID.join("_"))?GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")):tabsID[0];
activateTab(etTab[m]);`

})();